# R dplyr::c_across() strange behaviour in rowSums

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to see how to apply rowSums() to specific columns only.
here is a reprex:

```
df <- tibble(
  "ride" = c("bicycle", "motorcycle", "car", "other"),
  "A" = c(1, NA, 1, NA),
  "B" = c(NA, 2, NA, 2)
)
```

I can get the desired result, by index[2:3]

```
df %>%
  mutate(total = rowSums(.[2:3], na.rm = TRUE))

# A tibble: 4 × 4
  ride           A     B total
  <chr>      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 bicycle        1    NA     1
2 motorcycle    NA     2     2
3 car            1    NA     1
4 other         NA     2     2
```

however, if I try specifying columns by name, strange results occur

```
df %>%
  mutate(total = sum(c_across(c("A":"B")), na.rm = TRUE))

# A tibble: 4 × 4
  ride           A     B total
  <chr>      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 bicycle        1    NA     6
2 motorcycle    NA     2     6
3 car            1    NA     6
4 other         NA     2     6
```

What am I doing wrong?

I can achieve what I want, by something like this:

```
df %>%
  mutate_all(~replace(., is.na(.), 0)) %>%
  mutate(total = A + B)
```

but I'd like to specify column names by passing a vector, so I can change to different combination of column names in future.
Something like this is what I'd like to achieve:

```
cols_to_sum <- c("A","B")

df %>%
  mutate(total = sum(across(cols_to_sum), na.rm = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use `select` to specify the columns you want to `sum`.

```
library(dplyr)

cols_to_sum <- c("A","B")

df %>%
  mutate(total = rowSums(select(., all_of(cols_to_sum)), na.rm = TRUE))

#  ride           A     B total
#  <chr>      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 bicycle        1    NA     1
#2 motorcycle    NA     2     2
#3 car            1    NA     1
#4 other         NA     2     2
```

`c_across` works with `rowwise` -

```
df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(total = sum(c_across(all_of(cols_to_sum)), na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  ungroup
```

Comment: I've been learning new functions in dplyr 1.0 and may have been confusing myself haha. Thank you for the clear example and please have a lovely day!

Comment: `rowSums(across(all_of(cols_to_sum)))` is another option instead of  `select`.